# Adding drivers to already built CE 6.0 image

Tags: windows-ce

Is this possible? I am using a CE image from a manufacturer that won't release a custom image with an extra driver I need.

Give me some good news!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a possibility that you can add your driver over an existing image. You just need to place your driver dll(s) in the required folder (generally Windows folder) in your device where you want it to be and make some registry entries for it. If you already have a .reg file for the driver then you just need to import it on your device. 
You can also make a CAB file to avoid the manual work.

Comment: Thanks! There are some .bib files that come along with the driver. What do I do with them?

Comment: Did it! The driver is working. The .reg had some extra lines in it for other driver types (eg. an rs232 variant) but I just commented them out. Now if I could just get the calibration .exe working this screen would actually be helpful!

Comment: For posterity: this was a Beckhoff CX5010 PLC. I moved the .dll into the Hard Disk\System folder, and the .reg to the RegFiles directory. Ran the .reg. Restarted. Worked. For the PenMount USB resistive touch screen controller.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You need to have permanent registry and storage. If you have, then you can configure registry entries to load your driver (at boot or when is detected by USB, SD, PCI etc.) and store it on the device. In some cases drivers are loaded from the image before any storage is mounted and this may prevent you from being able to load your driver at boot (or having your device detected if it's plugged in at boot).

Comment: I believe I can actually configure this. There are instructions on the vendor site to set up stuff to add to the reg at boot. In fact, I just ran the .reg file and it seems like some entries stuck... Is there a way for me to determine what gets added by the .reg file?

Comment: Looks like registry is not permanent. Otherwise I see no point in importing something each time the device boots. I can't help you much, not knowing the specific device. You should check if on the internal flash or any persistent storage you have a system.hv file. This means that you have hive-based registry and that you can load a driver from the same storage. Otherwise you need to rely on vendor-specific solutions.

Comment: It seems registry edits are permanent. I stripped the .reg to just what I needed.